# Show popup with message in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I have site with Umbraco 4.9.0. My task is to show popup with message when user visits some pages for the first time in session.
How could I do it? I am a .Net developer and doesn't know anything much about Umbraco, except of the fact it is CMS and has been written on ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Why not use a cookie or a normal session variable? You don't have to make it Umbraco dependant (in fact, I don't think Umbraco can help you at all).

Comment: @JannikAnker but for this I have to extend Umbraco with my custom code, right? How could I do this?

Comment: You find the template files (or views, I guess) and alter them as uou would in any other ASP.NET solution :-) The functionality you want has nothing to do with Umbraco itself and so you don't have to deal with the Umbraco side of things

Comment: Maybe have a look at the documentation over at our.umbraco.org if you want to know where to find atuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to edit template .cshtml page and add html/JS/CSS code for simple plugin. No need to change something in Umbraco.